# Equivalent loop .first and .last (ORACLE) in POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In oracle i have this loop statement :

```
varPrefix:= nmr_objSeed.setCollection(varTplName);
            for item in varPrefix.first .. varPrefix.last loop
                  lines.text:= replace(lines.text, varPrefix(item).name, '');
            end loop;
```

what is the equivalent of "for i in column.first .. column.last loop" in POSTGRESQL ?

thank you !

Comment: What is `column` in this context? Please post a more complete example. Exactly what Oracle product are you using?

Comment: Before anything else, do you really need a LOOP? I always try to avoid them, they make things slow. And if you do need a LOOP, check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS

Comment: i changed the examlpe

Comment: Your code has two `end if;` statements but there's no opening `if` statements...

Comment: What data type is `varPrefix` in Postgres? If that is an array, you can use [foreach](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)

Comment: Where does lines.text come from? And how come you got this content without cleaning it, a step that you're now doing in the loop. My first impression is that this is a typical example where you don't need a loop at all. But without the entire code and requirements, hard to help you with this.

Comment: I agree that you may not need a loop at all. But to answer the question posed. In Oracle `for item in varPrefix.first .. varPrefix.last` iterates over the  collection varPrefix. In Postgres an array is closest  are to an Oracle collection. Iterating in Postgres the corresponding would be ` for item in 1 .. array_length(varPrefix,1)` or `foreach item in varPrefix`. However note that an Oracle collection is not exactly the same as a Postgres array.